# Telegram bot on Python, function is stuck at Await

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a telegram bot that retrieves a certain number of historical messages and does some processing on it.

Having trouble with the async/await functions in that they don't go on to the next line of code. I don't understand what it is waiting for to finish in order to proceed to the next line of code?

I've simplified my code while trying to replicate the problem and the problematic function i'm having is test() function when I call on the commmand /get.

The command /ping is just to see if it's communicating with Telegram servers and it does.

When calling /get, I get the terminal output

```
1
im here before
starting function
```

Which tells me that the code is getting stuck at the command `await client.start`
Any insight would be truly helpful

```
)

# Setting configuration values
api_id = xxxx
api_hash = xxxx
phone = xxxx
username_me = xxxx
group_username = xxxx
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
nest_asyncio.apply()

BOT_URL = xxxx
TOKEN = xxxxx
bot = xxxxx
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def pong(update,context):
    update.message.reply_text('Pong')

def start(update, context):  

    #Start Getting Messages
    all_messages = loop.run_until_complete(test())
    print('2')

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('ping',pong))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('get',start))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

async def test():
    print('im here before')
    await client.start
    print('im here after')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
'''
```